# Opening a VS 2003 C++ project in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, solution, visual-studio-2003

Found some old code, circa VS 2003. Now I have just VS 2008 (SP1) installed. When I try opening the *.sln file, it tries converting the projects. The report notifies me it was done successfully, but the solution is empty, marked with "project file was unloaded".
VS 2008 doesn't even include opening a *.vcproj file.

Does anyone have any idea how I can convert my solution?

PS: I found several conversion tools that convert from VS 2005 to 2008 and vice versa - no one looks back to 2003 :(

As always, thanks for your assistance and time!

Comment: PS: sorry about the mixup - turns up I didn't have C++ checked as a supported language during my VS2008 installation. Really silly of me. But the first answer was on the spot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest manually converting the project by creating a new proj.  If you are having trouble now then there will be no way that you can be certain later by trying some other import method.

On a side note- I am on vs2005 and I often get 2008 projects handed to me.  I go into the sln and proj files and rename the version numbers and it works perfectly.  Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could first convert your solution from VS2003 to VS2005 and then do one more conversion from VS2005 to VS2008 ???

Answer (score 0):

Seconding Klathzazts "manually changing the version numbers." this is often the best solution for dealing with VSC++ when something goes wrong in the upgrade process.